# Tracking bandwidth usage of my website run in IIS 7 / Windows

Tags: windows, iis-7

How to track bandwidth usage of my website run in IIS 7 / Windows?

Answer (score 0):

If it's hosted, then your hosting provider should provide you with gateway bandwidth usage at the port of your server. Otherwise, you could install a program such as DU Meter/Net meter, though this would log all traffic rather than just IIS. You could also analyse the logs from IIS using a program such as Weblog Expert- which provides bandwidth estimates.